# How does one sample a random walk on a circle with a Gaussian step size in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, simulation, random-walk

I am trying to obtain samples of a random walk on a circle that takes steps according to N(0, \sigma). To do this for a discrete random walk one calculates the cumulative sum of {+1,-1} coin tosses and then does mod the number of states on the circle at each step to obtain the current position. My question is: how to modify this for the continuous case?

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Comment: not sure, but does `cumsum(rnorm(n,0,sigma)) %% (2*pi)` do what you need?

Comment: What is Normally distributed in your example?  The distance of the arc round the circle or the angle of the position relative to some fixed reference?  Something else?  Also, I would say your example of a discrete RW is just a specific example.  It's not the only way of doing it.

Comment: @Limey I was thinking, it's the distance of the arc that should be Normal, but I'm just not sure how to draw samples of the walk in that case to show that the stationary distribution is Uniform. Btw, what's the other way to do a discrete RW? I've only heard of the one I mentioned above

Comment: @BenBolker yes, I think it does, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `N(0,sigma)` step distribution refers to the distribution of arc lengths around the circle, then

```
 cumsum(rnorm(n,0,sigma)) %% (2*pi)
```

should give a sample of the steps on the circle (in radians), starting from zero.